# Value from php is not passing properly to javscript function

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to pass a value by using onclick function from the server side data. That data that is loading to datatable from mysql . Here is my code

```
$nestedData[] = "<a href='javascript:' onclick='update_company_types('".$company_type."','". $id."')'><img src=".BASE_URL."public/assets/images/b_edit.png></a>";
```

But when I click on the edit icon I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. Some of the string values in MySql database are with spaces for example `dispatch center`, `new warehouse` etc.. and some of the values are without spaces. for ex: `carrier`, `logistic`.
If the value is without spaces then, it is working fine. But with spaces, I am getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. 
This is what I found from the console.

`<a href="javascript:" onclick="update_company_types(" dispatch="" center','30')'=""><img src="http://localhost/weex_material/public/assets/images/b_edit.png"></a>`

But in the database, the value is `Dispatch Center`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unescaped quotes inside `onclick` attribute.

```
$nestedData[] = "<a href='javascript:' onclick='update_company_types(\"".$company_type."\",\"". $id."\")'><img src=".BASE_URL."public/assets/images/b_edit.png></a>";
```

Comment: Now in console it is like this `<a href="javascript:" onclick="update_company_types(\" dispatch="" center\',\'30\')'=""><img src="http://localhost/weex_material/public/assets/images/b_edit.png"></a>`

Comment: You write `update_company_types(\"`, but there is no `\"` in my code... try to copy better :-)

Comment: @user3408779: I''ve updated my answer, I've put there escaped double quotes instead of single ones. But it should work both.